# Selecting the most recent date from a table in PeopleSoft using Peoplesoft Query (Max() doesn't work)

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplesoft-query

I am building a query in people soft using Peoplesoft query manager.

I am trying to pull the most recent date from the date column. I have tried using max() as an expression, however, the query doesn't pull any records. 
I have checked with another co-worker and they have never been able to pull records using max().

Is there any other way or workaround to pull the most recent record?

Comment: there is always `select top 1 date from table order by date desc`...which rdbms?

Comment: PeopleSoft HRMS 8.90 that uses Oracle

Comment: Run this and post: SELECT * FROM v$version

Comment: I can't run SQL, PeopleSoft generates that according to the expressions, criteria, having, prompts and records that you create via PeopleSoft. I would if I had access to SQL developer to alter the SQL code but unfortunately I do not. The max function seems to be working when one record is present but when I join multiple records it is returning nothing in the Query. Not sure what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out why no results were returned when using Max in a subquery. It was more from a lack of understanding PeopleSoft and SQL since I am relatively new to it. When I was setting the date column in the subquery as max for the aggregate to be used as criteria to compare to the date column in the main query I didn't make any criteria in the subquery. This meant that the subquery would go through all dates for all employees except for the employee that I was specifying in a prompt and returning a value that didn't match any of the dates for the employee in the main query and returning no one. This was fixed by setting a criteria in the subquery that the employee ID that had to be searched in the subquery matched the one that was typed into the prompt in the main query

Answer (score 0):

Use effective date for doing such searches while using PSQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use Effective date in order to get the most recent date, max may not work properly in PeopleSoft. Query should be effective dated

Answer (score 0):

PS Query has built in filters for EFFDT tables.  When you add a criteria on the EFFDT field, there are some additional drop down choices on the "condition type" field like 'Eff Date <' and 'Eff Date <=', etc.  Usually, when you create a query for an Effective dated table, PS Query will automatically add the subquery based on the 'Eff Date <=' condition type.